# How to interact with another application?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to make user actions in another application. Lets say, I would like to close Chrome's tab from my application. How can I achieve this using c++? Preferably Qt

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Chrome uses GTK 2) I don't see why a GUI framework matters in this case 3) you are probably violating X numbers of laws 4) it's not a good idea not even in a parallel universe.

Comment: I've only tried this once with C# myself so I'm commenting on my process rather than answering. I used a utility called **Winspector** (similar to Spy++) to identify a given window handle of the external application, then coded my application to seek out that particular handle, find its child window and grab its handle, then send Windows messages to it via [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/). It can be dangerous but something along those lines might achieve what you seek.

Comment: @user1824407, 3) and 4) are rubbish. Automates testing tools have being doing that since I don't know when.

Comment: Interprocess communication is highly operating-system dependent. Which operating system are you targeting?

Comment: Look up automated UI tests. Note this this stuff is extremely fragile, do not build this into a production app. If you want to control Chrome externally see what they provide API wise.

Comment: Sorry for deceiving you with Chrome, it was only meant to be an example. I just want to externally control other application UI's using my application.
@Philipp Lets say Windows 7, there are no constraints, I'm just wondering how it can be done

Comment: When I have done similar on windows (a decade ago) the solution was to directly send windows messages (like keystrokes and mouse clicks) to the window that you want to control.

Comment: On Windows (even on Windows 7) it can be done this way (having Administrator's rights) - you enumerate running processes (see sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx), get PID of the application wanted and kill the process. Disclaimer - never did it on Windows 7.

Comment: Wait a minute. Do you just want to kill applications or actually have your program interact with other application's GUI?

Comment: @drescherjm - He waits for an hour already) Probably, is afraid to decide "to kill or not to kill".

Comment: What you want requires the application to provide an interface to other application via some IPC service. There is no generic IPC mechanism supported for all platforms and all applications. You'll need to research about the specific applications you want to remote control.

Comment: @drescherjm - I want to interact with other app's GUI

Comment: Qt does not have support for that. However you can use winapi calls with Qt on the windows platform so you should be able to accomplish what Philipp said below. This is the basic approach you will need to take. Since this topic is closed we probably should end the discussion at this. If you need additional help you should open new topics. And make sure you are more specific next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, you can send events to another application using the WinAPI function [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This can be used to simulate user input for another application. In order to do so, you need to get its window handle (hWnd). You can do that with the WinAPI function [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).